# Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1364 [2] => Field 'access_code' doesn't have a default value )

Tags: php

When I try registering a new user I keep getting the above error and when I set the field to null or delete it, the form doesn't run. Here are the codes:

The user.php has the User Class with the Function to create new user as displayed below:

```
    <?php
// 'user' object 
/**
 * It is used for user object operations like creating a user deleting a user and more
 */
class User{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $email;
    public $contact_number;
    public $address;
    public $password;
    public $access_level;
    public $access_code;
    public $status;
    public $created;
    public $modified;

    // constructor
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    // check if given email exist in the database
function emailExists(){

    // query to check if email exists
    $query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, access_level, password, status
            FROM " . $this->table_name . "
            WHERE email = ?
            LIMIT 0,1";

    // prepare the query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // sanitize
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

    // bind given email value
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->email);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get number of rows
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    // if email exists, assign values to object properties for easy access and use for php sessions
    if($num>0){

        // get record details / values
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // assign values to object properties
        $this->id = $row['id'];
        $this->firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $this->lastname = $row['lastname'];
        $this->access_level = $row['access_level'];
        $this->password = $row['password'];
        $this->status = $row['status'];

        // return true because email exists in the database
        return true;
    }

    // return false if email does not exist in the database
    return false;
}
// create new user record
function create(){

    // to get time stamp for 'created' field
    $this->created=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // insert query
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                firstname = :firstname,
                lastname = :lastname,
                email = :email,
                contact_number = :contact_number,
                address = :address,
                password = :password,
                access_level = :access_level,
                status = :status,
                created = :created";

    // prepare the query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->firstname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->firstname));
    $this->lastname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->lastname));
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    $this->contact_number=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->contact_number));
    $this->address=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->address));
    $this->password=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));
    $this->access_level=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->access_level));
    $this->status=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->status));

    // bind the values
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $this->firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $this->lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contact_number', $this->contact_number);
    $stmt->bindParam(':address', $this->address);

    // hash the password before saving to database
    $password_hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

    $stmt->bindParam(':access_level', $this->access_level);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status', $this->status);
    $stmt->bindParam(':created', $this->created);

    // execute the query, also check if query was successful
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->showError($stmt);
        return false;
    }

}
// read all user records
function readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page){

    // query to read all user records, with limit clause for pagination
    $query = "SELECT
                id,
                firstname,
                lastname,
                email,
                contact_number,
                access_level,
                created
            FROM " . $this->table_name . "
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT ?, ?";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

    // bind limit clause variables
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // return values
    return $stmt;
}

// used for paging users
public function countAll(){

    // query to select all user records
    $query = "SELECT id FROM " . $this->table_name . "";

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    // get number of rows
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    // return row count
    return $num;
}



public function showError($stmt){
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    echo "</pre>";
}
}
```

My register.php is:

```
<?php
// core configuration
include_once "config/core.php";

// set page title
$page_title = "Register";

// include login checker
include_once "login_checker.php";

// include classes
include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';
include_once "libs/php/utils.php";

// include page header HTML
include_once "layout_head.php";

echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";

    // registration form HTML will be here
    // code when form was submitted will be here
// if form was posted
if($_POST){

    // get database connection
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize objects
    $user = new User($db);
    $utils = new Utils();

    // set user email to detect if it already exists
    $user->email=$_POST['email'];

    // check if email already exists
    if($user->emailExists()){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
            echo "The email you specified is already registered. Please try again or <a href='{$home_url}login'>login.</a>";
        echo "</div>";
    }

    else{
        // create user will be here
        // set values to object properties
$user->firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$user->lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$user->contact_number=$_POST['contact_number'];
$user->address=$_POST['address'];
$user->password=$_POST['password'];
$user->access_level='Customer';
$user->status=1;

// create the user
if($user->create()){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
        echo "Successfully registered. <a href='{$home_url}login'>Please login</a>.";
    echo "</div>";

    // empty posted values
    $_POST=array();

}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Unable to register. Please try again.</div>";
}
    }
}

//Registration form
?>
<form action='register.php' method='post' id='register'>

    <table class='table table-responsive'>

        <tr>
            <td class='width-30-percent'>Firstname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='firstname' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['firstname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='lastname' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['lastname']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Contact Number</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='contact_number' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['contact_number']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_number'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea name='address' class='form-control' required><?php echo isset($_POST['address']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' class='form-control' required id='passwordInput'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Register
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
<?php

echo "</div>";

// include page footer HTML
include_once "layout_foot.php";
?>
```

What do I need to do, please? If I have left something out in asking the question, please tell me.

Comment: That is an issue in the db table - set a default value (`NULL` perhaps ) or include that column in the `insert` statement with a value of some sort. The value you assign depends entirely on what that column represents and what the average user should have if an alternative value is not provided

Comment: In your table, column "access_code", here is the issue. alter your table and set a default value (at least null as default) to this column.

Comment: One other thing to mention. Do NOT sanitize the user's password before using `password_hash` as it can potentially change the value and render the user's password obsolete... Using the prepared statement renders the data safe for input, but take measures to cleanse when displaying on any page subsequently